# putting a double[] inside a field of a document

Tags: java, mongodb, document

I am trying to create a document and then put it inside a mongo database.
When creating the document, one of the fields is of type `double[]`.
I use the next line of code to add this field to the document:

```
Document loc = new Document();
loc.put("position", new Document("type", "Point").append("cords", new double[]{32.05, 35.15}));
```

When i try to print out the content of the `position` field i get the next output:
`position = Document{{type=Point, cords=[D@d455b8}}`

I use the next code to print it out:

```
private void printout(Document d){
    Set<Entry<String, Object>> ks = d.entrySet();
    for (Entry e : ks){
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + " = " + e.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

The question is why am i not seeing the actual numbers when i print out the document keys and values?
Another question is, will i be able to use the `$near` operator to locate the document has a position closest to some other position if i store the document this way?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it correct. The reason that printing isn't working has nothing to do with mongodb.

Just try out the following:

```
    double [] cords = new double[]{32.05, 35.15};
    System.out.println(cords);//outputs [D@311d617d
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cords)); // outputs [32.05, 35.15]
```

A readable way of printing arrays is using `Arrays.toString(..)`. That's what is happening in your for loop. But it'll get converted to the right BSON type before insertion.

It also looks fine for being used in `$near` queries.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: How will i be able to reach the content of this array if needed? I have tried using `loc.get("position").get("cords")[0]` but its hasnt been working.

Comment: I have tried to put the document inside the mongo database and i got the next error: ` org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class [D.`.  That problem regards the array field. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Apparently one should use a list in order to insert an array into the mongoDB document.

```
List<Double> cordlist = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
        cordlist.add(32.05); 
        cordlist.add(35.15);
        loc.put("position", new Document("type", "Point").append("cords", cordlist));
```